# EF Core не работает ни один из select методов

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, rest, entity-framework-core

Не работают ни FirstOrDefault,ни FirstOrDefaultAsync, ни Find в одном контроллере.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "master,admin,super,foreman")]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(long id, [FromBody]DutyForCuteMaterial duty)
    {
        var dutyInDB = db.DutyForCuteMaterials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        int day = dutyInDB.CloseDate.DayOfYear;
        string status = dutyInDB.Status;
        if (id != duty.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        if (duty.CloseDate.DayOfYear != day)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        if (status != "Закрыт")
        {
            duty.Status = "Закрыт";
            db.Entry(duty).State =  EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();
        }
        else return BadRequest();
    }
```

Переменные не отображаются, а точки остановки просто проскакивают мимо.
Во всех остальных методах все работает отлично.
HELP

Вот что происходит при попытке поставить точку остановки после запуска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне вывода без конца мелькает исключение
"System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException" в System.Net.Sockets.dll

Comment: оберните всё в try catch и посмотрите ошибку

Comment: Ошибок нет, оно даже не попадает на эти строки, и не важно вызываю синхронно метод или асинхронно.

Comment: Начинается выполнения запроса на получение, после чего сразу прыгает на If, проходит все, после чего на обновлении состояния duty выполнение просто прекращается(без ошибок) После окончания выполнения получаю "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll . Но до строк с получение записи так и не доходит

Comment: Переменные ведут себя абсолютно непредсказуемо, проверяет условия с переменной "status", но точка останова через нее даже не проходила, в итоге переменной как бы нет, но if=true

Comment: В итоге ответ найден в этом посте
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t